# Point source pollution model for South America

Tags: models, hydrology, pollution, software

I want to model point source pollution in S. America watersheds. Specifically, given a set of pollution points and corresponding pollution output levels, I want to know the course these pollutants will take in the watershed and the accumulation levels.

Is there software that will do this?

Comment: Are you looking to write your own code for this? Can you give some more detail on what exactly you need? Is this basically like particle tracking in rivers?

Comment: @IsopycnalOscillation I'd like to be able to specify, say, 10 pollution outputting points. I'd then like to be able to track the pollution throughout the watersheds. Ideally, I'd like to be able to track the accumulation levels of the pollutant throughout the watershed. However, a binary for whether the area becomes polluted would also suffice. I'd be willing to write some code, but I'd prefer to find a solution that minimizes my own development. I was hoping something like ArcGIS had these capabilities.

Comment: i haven't used it in years, but wonder if the [swat](http://swat.tamu.edu) model would do this? it has plugins for both arcgis and qgis.